# Change color of matching characters in autocomplete with Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an autocomplete search field connected to my apiurl
[image]

What I wan't to do (but I have no idea how can I do this with TypeScript or Angular)is: change text color and make them bold ONLY to matching letters in dropdown with those whic i write in input field..

ANGULAR:

```
            <form class="mt-4 mb-4">
            <mdb-form-control class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <input mdbInput autocomplete="off" type="text" list="joblistOptions" class="form-control" name="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="onChange()"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="text">Vpišite poklic, o katerem bi želeli izvedeti več</label>
            </mdb-form-control>
            <div *ngIf="showResults" class="autocomplete-dropdown">
                <ul class="autocomplete-item-list">
                    <li class="autocomplete-item" *ngFor="let job of filteredJobs" [routerLink]="['/job-description',job.nadnaslov]">{{ job.nadnaslov }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
text: string = '';
showResults: boolean = false;
testJobs: any;
filteredJobs: any;

private jobsSubs: Subscription = new Subscription();

constructor(private jobsService: JobsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllJobs();
}

onChange() {
  if (this.text.length > 0) {
  this.showResults = true;
  } else {
    this.showResults = false;
  }

if (this.text.length === 1) {
  //console.log('test');
  this.filteredJobs = this.testJobs.filter((job:any) => job.nadnaslov.split('')[0] === this.text);
} 
else if (this.text.length >= 2){
  this.filteredJobs = this.testJobs.filter((testJobs:any) => testJobs.nadnaslov.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.text.toLocaleLowerCase()));
} 
else {
  this.filteredJobs = [];
}

if (this.filteredJobs.length === 0) {

}
}

getAllJobs() {
  this.jobsService.getJobs().subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.testJobs = response;
    this.filteredJobs = response;
  });
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-angular6-fmdzze

Take note: it's a basic example, but keeping the appropriate logic and structure of your project (the parts that you shared). You will have to play with html template though, to make it work for your mdb-form-control. You'd also need to add your `[routerLink]`.

Essentially, I'm changing the .nadnaslov value for a job that matches the input text, by wrapping the matching substring with `<span>` that has a style added to it (like color: red), and then displaying it as innerHtml of a li.

The method first removes all added tags (if the filteredJobs is already changed by previous typing) to return to 'original' .nadnaslov values. Then your own logic goes - populating the filteredJobs. After that, if filteredJobs has content (length > 0), I wrap the .nadnaslov as explained.

Note that there's a pipe added, to block sanitization of html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am really close to the solution with your help. https://imgur.com/a/BqTjzEW . Probably something with the regex maybe

Comment: Check if you're adding whitespaces before and after the wrapping-tags. or before/after wrapped parts of job.nadnaslov. Also check what your css for results list is doing to display.

Comment: Check screenshots maybe you will see the mistake: https://imgur.com/a/XCHRWxP

Comment: Not yet sure about styling, but for routerLink you'll have to do something else, since job.nadnaslov will now have those span additions and will not work. So maybe you can put `this.filteredJobs[i].routerlink = job.nadnaslov;` below the comment 'priprava da se displaya...', and then in template instead of `[routerLink]="['/job-description', job.nadnaslov]"` you do `[routerLink]="['/job-description', job.routerlink ]"`

Comment: What are the details of `autocomplete-item` css class?

Comment: I am assuming that problem is not in the routerlink, because even if I remove [routerLink]="['/job-description', job.nadnaslov]", displayed text in drpodown is still broken

Comment: Yeah, those are not related, it was just a comment on links themselves :)

Comment: This is complete css: https://imgur.com/a/bX3w4TD

Comment: Can you put the styles in that stackblitz I posted? Kinda hard to type it all out xD

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-angular6-z85qk8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: I actually now what is problem,  (it is default in _autocomplete.scss). display: flex;. If i remove this in inspector it works in broswer editor. https://imgur.com/a/PCuwbeB
But if i override it with like display:initial !important I lose those nice dropdown :S

Comment: I solved it. Adding style="justify-content: start !important;" to my <li> tag solved my problem. Thank you for your help so much

Comment: Glad you solved it! Vso srečo :)

Comment: Thank you, hvala :D

Comment: Eh, if you think the answer has solved your issue, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: Can you tell me whre I can accept the answer? I can't find it haha. And maybe, Can i ask you a question in private chat? Like on linkedin or twitter or facebook? If yes, I will post here my link.

Comment: Hey not sure about how to accept - I asked only 1 q so far and got no answers xD Anyway, yeah, reach me on fb, same username

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update DOM for changing colors.

I would suggest making some changes in this piece of code to add 2 elements, one for bold, and changed color text.

```
<li class="autocomplete-item" *ngFor="let job of filteredJobs" [routerLink]="['/job-description',job.nadnaslov]">
   <span class="bold color">{{job.boldText}}</span>
   <span>{{ job.nadnaslov }}</span>
</li>
```

Then you can add a CSS class for each color, and replace it by adding a new attribute to each job named class.

```
<li class="autocomplete-item" *ngFor="let job of filteredJobs" [routerLink]="['/job-description',job.nadnaslov]">
   <span class="bold {{job.class}}">{{job.boldText}}</span>
   <span>{{ job.nadnaslov }}</span>
</li>
```

After this, you will need to update your ts file so that you can get, and update job objects in the array accordingly.

Not a perfect solution, but it'll work for you

Comment: I can't make it work for dynamic changing colors sadly. Do you have any idea what to do in typescript for this?

Comment: All you have to do is define classes regarding colors, and assign the value to job.class attribute